# New switch ports to be correctly identified as Common (Red) and Neutral

Tags: switch, neutral

Need to identify the correct porst for Common (Red) and Neutral (Black) on new switch backplane. I have indicated as "1" where the Common --Red wire should connect. The word Loop is between two ports. Which one is neutral "2" or "3"?  Thanks.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What country is this? What is on the other side of this plate? I suppose this is another British Commonwealth device which makes some connections that we in N. America make in a different way?

Comment: Australia.  Australia uses British  & European standarads.

Comment: Is there anything (e.g., , switch lever) on the other side of this device or is this a cover for a junction box that has a connection block incorporated into the inside surface? How would it be used?

Comment: See double switch  front Jim. Two switches for two separate devices.  <Hope the picture is displayed>

Comment: Nifty device. In the US, at least in the past, we would have used a 2-gang box, separate switches, generally clunkier arrangement of wires connected by twist on wire connectors. I see we do have double switches available but I have never even examined one. Probably this poster's device does not accept aluminum conductor, but did Commonweath codes ever accept aluminum?

Comment: @JimStewart  this scheme of switches that clip into the front plate was invented some time in the 1980s and has since them come to dominate with similar (but incompatible) offerings from many brands.  They make front plates with places for up-to 6 switches in a single gang box,  (same size and screw patterns as US single gang) as all the splices can be made at the switch  that saves a lot of room in the junction box.  I can't speak on box fill  rules, I leave that stuff to electricians. the switch modules can be removed and turned in steps of 90 deg or replaced with dimmers or indicators etc

Answer (score 2):

They are labeled, try angling the illumination so that the surface texture is more visible.

I see an indistinct "2" here.

[image]

Anyway your "3" almost certainly loop, which is where neutral connects

Comment: Thanks Jasen. One issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

They are usually labelled.

- Red arrow is phase or line or mains
- Blue arrow is Load (Bulb, device etc)
- The blocked off hole is if you want reverse action or a two way switch (it connects when the switch is off.  It is called normally closed)
- Label 3 is a Loop (provided where you can loop the neutral or ground, ie connect two neutral wires together).  It is not connected to anything.

Comment: Thanks guys. The blocked off hole is confusing as I do not know why it has a screw. So Loop is for neutral.  Is the open/close switch between #1 (mains/Common)  and #2 ( red to bulb) then? Appreciate your responses.